# remove tvOS build from iTunesconnect

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode7, appstore-approval, tvos

I have added tvOS app in itunesconnect now while submission of app, it is asking for tv os privacy policy...how can i remove tvOS app from itunesconnect or submit my build without providing tvOS privacy policy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove tvOS app from iTunes Connect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801488/how-to-remove-tvos-app-from-itunes-connect)

Comment: ya..but there i don't seem any solution..

Comment: You can't submit a build for review without a privacy policy.  You can reject a binary to keep it from being reviewed.   You can also change the app name to some dummy name ("ignoreMe_SomeRandomNumber")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to submit my build by adding few comments in tvOS privacy policy section like this policy is not required for submitting iOS apps..